# any way to make validation data from `tfds` data in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am curious about making validation dataset from `tensorflow_datasets` in tensorflow because it is not clear to me how to split training data that come from `tfds`. I understand it is easy to make validation data by using `train_test_split` from `sklearn`, but I am not sure how should do that for data from `tfda`. Does anyone knows possible way of doing this? any thoughts?

**attempt**

I could make validation data as follow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

(X_tr, y_tr), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_tr, y_tr, test_size=0.1, stratify=y_tr)
```

but how should we make validation data from this:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
mnst= tfds.load('mnist')
train_data = mnst['train']
test_data = mnst['test']
```

from this how can we make validation data? any quick thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loading the data you can specify splits, like this:

```
(train_data, validation_data) = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:]'],
    as_supervised=True,
)
```

Splits can be specified as `'train'` and `'test'`. [From the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits):

> All DatasetBuilders expose various data subsets defined as splits (eg:
> train, test)

They can be checked with a simple way also:

```
(training_set, validation_set, test_set) = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:]', 'test'],
    as_supervised=True,
)
```

Convert them into numpy arrays and check their shape, will be showing only one for demo, others follow the same logic, we make the `tfds` iterable with `as_numpy`:

```
test_set = tfds.as_numpy(test_set)

x_test = [] # will be containing numpy arrays, I defined them as a list to check.
y_test = []


for features_labels in test_set: # features_labels is a tuple 
                                 # containing features and labels here.
    x_test.append(features_labels[0])
    y_test.append(features_labels[1])
    
x_test = np.array(x_test)    
y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

Now you can check the shapes:

```
x_test.shape
>>> (10000, 28, 28, 1)

y_test.shape
>>> (10000,)


x_val.shape
>>> (12000, 28, 28, 1)


x_train.shape
>>> (48000, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: how about testing data? validation data is taken from training data, right? and `tfds.load('mnist')` will return training data and testing data. Can you elaborate little bit if we could pass split argument in the function? Any idea?

Comment: I edited the answer if I understood you correct.